# PHP foreach result in new line

Tags: php, foreach, line-breaks

```
$url = "http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/character/haomarush/caffer/advanced";
$html = file_get_html($url);
foreach($html->find('ul.summary-audit-list') as $e)


echo $e->plaintext;
```

I'd like to echo every result to have <.br/> tag behind it.

```
echo $e->plaintext."<br />";
```

doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

```
$url = "http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/character/haomarush/caffer/advanced";
$html = file_get_html($url);
foreach($html->find('ul.summary-audit-list') as $e)
    echo $e->plaintext."<br />";
```

if you just want a new line without the

```
<br />
```

use "\n" ... which is a short for new line

if your $e->plaintext contains any other tags like

```
'<li>'
```

you can do something like this if you have `<li> with <span>` like in your example

```
echo str_replace(array("</li>", "</span>"), array("</li>\n", "</span>\n"), $e->plaintext);
```

Comment: Already tried it all different ways. For some reason it just won't work. All I can say the obvious answer isn't working which is really annoying right now.

Comment: what did you try? if $e->plaintext is not empty and valid the above should give you a br after each line... if you want to use "\n" be shure that you use the double quotes " not the single ones '

Comment: Right now result is foo bar<br/> i'd like it to be foo<br/>bar    Also if I try echo     $e->plaintext."bla"; it will be foo barbla which tells me that foreach wouldn't even be required although when doing it without foreach I get result array. Man confusing to just write this... ;P

Comment: its hard to help here if i dont know what the string is you have... f.e. if your $e->plaintext contains any other tags like <li> you can do something like this ´echo str_replace('</li>', "</li>\n", $e->plaintext);´

Comment: can you echo $html = file_get_html($url); contents. You must get as some results of that output.

Comment: check the last edit.. I think it will work fine for this example

Answer (score 0):

You have

echo $e->plaintext."
"

But when you concatenate you an do

echo $e->plaintext."
"

You also should do this instead to print out your results

```
    foreach($e as $row){


        print $row."<br>";


    }
```